# How to make a npm command, that executes two commands in the console (one after another)?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, http, npm

How can I make a command in the package.json file, that executes two commands for the terminal (console) one after another?

---

This question refers to **node.js** and **NPM package**.

I have a **"server" folder** in which I installed **http server** and **npm package.json file**, and there is also a folder **"webdir"** (inside **"server"** folder) with a web page.

I can run the web server manually, or by typing in the terminal: `node [path to the file that runs the server]`, but I need this to happen automatically on command `npm start`. And the server must be activated from the **"webdir" folder**, so that I could immediately go to my web page at `localhost: 8080`.

To do this, I need to write in the terminal (console) two commands one after another:

1. `cd webdir`
2. `node [path to the file that runs the Web server]`

How to make a npm command, that executes **two commands** in the console **(one after another)**?

Here is the working code with a single line script:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node (...)/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server"
  },
```

Comment: could possibly use semicolon do break the commands, something like `cd /where/ever ; node /some/file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax I'm aware of involves using `&&` to separate the commands, i.e.

```
"cd webdir && node ..."
```

This should work both on Windows and on Unix based systems.

For example, jQuery uses such combined statements in its deploy scripts:

```
"build": "npm install && grunt",
"start": "grunt watch",
"test": "grunt && grunt test:slow",
"precommit": "grunt lint:newer",
"commitmsg": "node node_modules/commitplease"
```

See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! And semicolon also works! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try a semi-colon after your first CLI statement, then your second statement after the semi-colon.