# How to execute two NPM commands sequentially copying a file as the last step?

Tags: angular, powershell, npm, post-build-event, npm-scripts

I've altered my *package.json* scripts as follows (suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39172660/1525840) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38927990/1525840)). It works and does what's expected.

```
...
"deploy": "ng build && echo Do not forget to copy web.config!", ...
```

Then, I tried to substitute the echoing into actually copying a file like this.

```
...
"deploy": "ng build && copy ./src/web.config ./dist", ...
```

However, this fails with the error below.

> ''copy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I know that I can resolve this task by Grunting or Gulping but I'd like to keep it simple and see if it's possible. Is it?

I've tried to surround the paths with apostrophes and even running the copy command as a single command of the script. No luck.

Comment: how does it fail ? is there any error ?

Comment: @n00dl3 Sorry about that. I pasted in an older version of the question. Please see the current one. As for your question - the error says that there's no such command, more or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copy` is not a valid bash command. Try using [`cp`](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/cp/) instead.

You can write a nodejs script that just copies that file.

copy.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.createReadStream('./src/web.config')
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./dist/web.config'));

...
"deploy": "ng build && node run ./copy.js .
```

I got it running using M$-DOS [`COPY`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html). It also works using PowerShell using `Copy-Item`.

Don't forget you have to use backslashes on M$, which you also need to escape.

`"deploy": "COPY .\\a\\test .\\b\\test"`
or
`"deploy": "Copy-Item .\\a\\test .\\b\\test"`